# How to allow more roles can add users in Drupal 7?

Tags: users

I have created Four Roles – A, B, C, D

Home » Administration » Configuration » People – I have set visitors can create an account. A, B, C roles could register from my front end site. And I want that My C role users could create A and D role accounts. I have assigned permissions “Administer users” and “View user profiles” to my C role user. Now my C role user can view link “admin/people”. Here I want to control “Show only users where” and “Update options” form. 
Just like - “Show only users where” form shows only two roles A and D and other relevant thinks

Please give me some advice...

My English is not good... Sorry for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Views and Views_bulk_update module. First, install both these modules. Don't forget to enable views_ui module also.

Then go to Structure->Views. Create a new view with page-display and fetching user's data.

Now, add the relevant fields there, like user-name, email etc. Now, in the filter section, add a filter of "role" and expose it. You can add more filters and expose them.

Also, add fields regarding bulk operations and select the operations you wish to perform e.g. changing email, deleting user.

Now, give this page a "path" in the page-setting section.

Finally, save this view and go to the path you gave it. It should be up and running.

PS: If you couldn't comprehend above, you will need to learn views module. It's a very powerful module and needs some time to grasp. See some videos on youtube to learn it. For your simple purpose, it would take an hour or so to learn.